# Rails 6: How to conditionally validate an association for presence?

Tags: validation, associations, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following 2 models:

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings
end

class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :offer
end
```

When I attempt to save a Booking object without an offer_id, Rails throws a validation error "Offer is required".

But I don't actively validate for presence of associated objects (I intended to add a conditional validation for this association later).

Does that mean that Rails 6 validates the presence of all associations by default? And if yes, how can I make such a validation a conditional one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from Rails 5, `belongs_to` adds presence validation by default. 
You can disable this behavior in `application.rb` with:

```rb
config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

Or if you want it to be optional only in this `belongs_to` you can pass `optional` option to belongs_to:

```rb
belongs_to :offer, optional: true
```

Comment: Thank you! And to make it a conditional validation, I'd have to add it manually again, as a normal (conditional) validation like `validates :offer, presence: true, if: my_condition`, right?